# Using "the" in a sentence?

Tags: articles

Coming to improve my skills and acquire knowledge while meeting ***the organization’s goals.***

Is it "the organization's goals" or just "organization's goals" without "the"?

Knowing that I mentioned the organization name before this sentence

Answer (score 1):

If your company's name is FooBar, Inc., you'd typically say something like

> Here at FooBar, ... knowledge while meeting FooBar's goals.

Or you could say

> Here at FooBar, ... knowledge while meeting the company's goals.

Use of 'the' will depend on whether you describe FooBar as a company or refer to it by name. 
You can also use the word 'company' to describe the goals in question:

> Here at FooBar, ... knowledge while meeting company goals.

The last is a little less common I think and I would find it slightly harder to parse, personally.